# Quiero hacer un ListView con la siguiente data

Tags: java, android, android-layout, object, programación-móvil

Estoy tratado de crear un ListView o ExpandableListView, con la data recolectada en mi objecto Articulo

Quiero que toda esta quede parecido a esto:

*Nombre Articulo 1

-id

-nom

*Nombre Articulo 2

-id

-nom

```
public class DetallesArticulosActivity extends RoboAppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Object objs = getIntent().getSerializableExtra(PrincipalInventarioActivity.ARTICULOS_SELECCIONADOS);
            Articulo[] articulos;
            if (objs instanceof Articulo[]) {
                articulos = (Articulo[]) objs;
            } else {
                Object[] os = (Object[]) objs;
                articulos = new Articulo[os.length];
                int i = 0;
                for (Object obj : os) {
                    articulos[i++] = (Articulo) obj;
                }
            }

            ArrayList<Articulo> Eventos = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Articulo articulo : articulos) {
                Eventos.add(articulo);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Los pasos serian: 1.- Googlear como hacer una lista, 2.- Hacer la lista, 3.- Probar, 4.- Si algo falla repetir los pasos X veces, 5.- Si despues X veces no te funciono, escribe una pregunta en stackoverflow mostrando lo que hiciste.